# Unity C#: Can't change position or rotation of a new object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm trying to implement a teleportation effect and need to spawn a new camera at the teleport destination. However, no matter what I try I can't change the position and rotation of the newly instantiated camera and it doesn't even spawn where I tell it to. Here's the spawn code along with some debug output:

```cs
Camera targetCamera = Object.Instantiate
(
    cameraPrefab, 
    camera.transform.position,
    camera.transform.rotation
);
Debug.Log(camera.name + ": " + camera.transform.position + ", " 
    + targetCamera.name + ": " + targetCamera.transform.position);
Debug.Log(camera.name + ": " + camera.transform.rotation + ", "
    + targetCamera.name + ": " + targetCamera.transform.rotation);
```

Right after the debug output I pause the program.

[image: This is how the scene looks before starting]

camera in the code refers to the Main Camera object.

[image: Here's where the new camera spawns, camera circled in red is the Main Camera]

The position and rotation outputs of both camera objects are completely different from what it says in the Inspector:

[image: Main Camera values]

[image: targetCamera values]

[image: Debug output]

So not only does the targetCamera not spawn where I tell it to but the debug and Inspector values are completely different, too.

I already tried setting the targetCamera position and rotation again after instantiating it but that doesn't do anything. I also tried creating a new XROrigin object using a prefab, attaching the targetCamera to that and using XROrigin.MoveCamerToWorldLocation but that doesn't move it to the correct location, either. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what do you think should be moving the targetcamera? you have no code to move it.. you spawn it where the "camera" object is.. and thats it, and if your "cameraprefab" is not on 0,0,0 it will offset.. so.. theres a lot not covered here

Comment: Note that values displayed in the Inspector are always the **local** ones relative to their according parent object ... at last your `Main Camera` is nested under `XROrigin` which might have an offset position and rotation relative to world space itself => more reliable might be to rather spawn this new camera as a child of the existing one, reset **local**Position and **local**Rotation to zero and then de-parent it maintaining the current world space values

Comment: I'd expect the targetCamera to spawn where I tell it to when using Instantiate but it doesn't

Comment: Is there maybe any script on he spawned camera that changes it's position as well? Or maybe it is trapped by any VR / XROrigin related thing and gets its position overwritten?

Comment: I can't believe I sat here over an hour trying to understand this.... I created the prefab from a new camera object and it obviously still had the trackedPoseDriver component... Removing that fixed it, thanks so much